# Printing all elements of table in Fortran form

Tags: export, list-manipulation, fortran

Let's say I have some `Table` object. The elements of this table are accessed as `Table[[i,j,k]]`.

For each element in the array I want to convert it to `FortranForm` and then construct a string of the form `STRING_IJK = value` where `value` is the specific table element `FortranForm[Table[[i,j,k]]]`.

I then want to save all of these strings to an external file.

Is there a method to do this? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your table is called something like `myTable`:

```
fortranTable = Flatten[Table[
  "STRING_" <> ToString[i] <> ToString[j] <> ToString[k] <> " = " <> 
  ToString[myTable[[i, j, k]] // FortranForm], 
  {i, Dimensions[myTable][[1]]}, 
  {j, Dimensions[myTable][[2]]},
  {k, Dimensions[myTable][[3]]}]]
```

`<>` is the concatenation operator for strings, so I'm just converting the indices to strings and then joining them together. I have an expression like x^26 in position 111, I get: `STRING_111 = x**26`.

**EDIT:**

If you want to export the final table, the following works but tweaks can be made depending on exactly what you want the output to look like.

```
Export["filelocation/filename.txt", fortranTable]
```

I believe you can use either double backslashes `\\` to separate the parts of file names or a single slash, and of course `filelocation` and `filename` should be changed to suit your needs, but the quotation marks are required. This should give you a file where each entry in the table has its own line (that is, they're separated by '\n').

Comment: This is great. Is there a way to then save the output to file?

Comment: @user1887919 I've edited my answer to include the export as well.